# adding typescript internal references

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define my own model interface that extends the seqeulize model instance and I'm having trouble referencing the seqeulize interface from my code.

I get the error "Cannot find name 'seqeuelize'

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

interface IUser extends sequelize.Instance<TInstance, TPojo> {
```

I've added seqeulize via tsd install --save .

What am I doing wrong - should I be importing it even though its only being used for type reference?

and in sequlize.d.ts

```
declare module "sequelize"
{
    module sequelize {
       interface Model<TInstance, TPojo> extends Hooks, Associations {
```

Comment: I can't help but notice that you've spelt "sequelize" a handful of different ways in your question, which could be related to the problem you're experiencing! Having said that, the spelling in the code seems consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an external module, so in addition to referencing `tsd.d.ts`, you need to `import` the module:

```
import sequelize = require('sequelize');
```

Comment: that seems to have removed the error from the IUser file, but now it says that it "Cannot find name 'IUser' in the controller file that is referencing it

Comment: removing the import sequelize line from iuser.ts solves that error but then brings up the issue of not being able to extend from the sequelize interface